# Site-specific information in Help Centre for "What types of question should I avoid asking?"

Tags: feature-request, help-center

I've noticed that [the page in the Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) describing what questions you shouldn't ask appears to be the same for all sites (I've tried three, so I might be wrong.) Mostly, these tips probably are broadly applicable enough to cover all sites, but there are some sites where they seem out of place. For example, this paragraph:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

This seems weird on Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, or Code Review, where even these template questions aren't in any way applicable. While this is all technically true, because these questions wouldn't be valid on any site, I think that the don't ask page should contain specific information for each site, at least for sites that deviate from the Q&A format like PCG or CR. Knowing what's *not* okay is just as important to me as knowing what is okay, when participating in a new community, but these pages don't give much insight.